# Python: Comparing Two lists

Tags: python, list, set, compare

I am trying to compare these two lists using Python:

```
comp1 = [['set',1,2]]
comp2 = [['set',2,1]]
```

Both are valid representations of the set, {1,2}

I essentially want to check if these lists, comp1 and comp2 are equal to each other but I am unsure how to go about this in Python.

I am also interested in finding out how I would do this with lists like:

```
comp3 = [['set',1,2],['set',3,4]]
comp4 = [['set',2,1],['set',4,3]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
comp3 = [set(L[1:]) for L in comp3]
comp4 = [set(L[1:]) for L in comp4]

comp3 == comp4  # this should do the trick
```

Comment: I tried this but I get TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' when trying to run it

Answer (score 2):

just for fun, if you want the type to be inferred by the first string. you could pick it up from the `__builtin__` module.

```
def typify(seq):
    seq = iter(seq)
    typestr = next(seq)
    return getattr(__builtin__, typestr)(seq)

comp3 = list(map(typify, comp3))
```

the function takes the first argument, find the equivalent type from the `__builtin__` module, apply it to the rest of the sequence.
We can then `map` this function on all the sub-elements of you list comp3.
On python2 `map` will return a list, while in python3 you will have to explicitly convert it, otherwise it will just leave you a generator.

This is general enough so that if you pass a different type, it will recognize it automatically:

```
comp3 = [['list',1,2],['set',3,4]]
list(map(typify, comp3))
#[[1, 2], {3, 4}]
```

after that you can just do

```
comp3 = [['set',1,2],['set',3,4]]
comp4 = [['set',2,1],['set',4,3]]

comp3 = list(map(typify, comp3))
comp4 = list(map(typify, comp4))

comp3 == comp4
```

Comment: This is cool, I never realized I could `getattr` from `__builtin__` lol, thought of doing something with eval, but that could lead to a disaster

Comment: it always depend on the source...if you are getting data from outside yes, it would be dangerous, but if you are the source, `eval` could be useful to use with non builtin classes like `OrderedDict` or similar

Answer (score 0):

What about this approach (using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)):

```
>>> comp3 = [['set',1,2],['set',3,4]]
>>> comp4 = [['set',2,1],['set',4,3]]
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> print set(chain(*comp3))
set([3, 1, 2, 'set', 4])
>>> set(chain(*comp3)) == set(chain(*comp4))
True
>>>
```